# python json как вывести все данные json

Tags: python, json, requests

есть вот такой код который получает ответ от сервера с помощью библиотеки requests.

```
import requests
import json
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
r = requests.get(f'https://www.pochta.ru/api/tracking/api/v1/trackings/by-barcodes?language=ru&track-numbers=', verify=False)
data = r.json()
print(data['detailedTrackings'][0]['trackingItem']['trackingHistoryItemList'][0]['humanStatus'])
```

Этот код получает json с сервера почты России по трек коду. Мне нужно вывести все статусы отправления HumanStatus из trackingHistoryItemList. Сейчас выводит статус Сортировка. И ещё как можно выводить конкретный статус Получено адресатом если он есть trackingHistoryItemList

```
{
  "trackingsDto": null,
  "detailedTrackingsWithMultiMailDto": null,
  "detailedTrackings": [
    {
      "userTrackingItemId": null,
      "trackingItem": {
        "destinationCountryName": "Россия",
        "destinationCountryNameGenitiveCase": "России",
        "title": "Мелкий пакет из Китая",
        "trackingHistoryItemList": [
          {
            "date": "2023-01-10T10:06:17.041+03:00",
            "humanStatus": "Получено адресатом",
          },
          {
            "date": "2022-12-01T11:54:19.000Z",
            "humanStatus": "Подготовлено к отправке",
          }
        ],
        "globalStatus": "ARCHIVED",
        "mailType": "Мелкий пакет",
      },
      "alienOrder": null,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [0] означает, что ты обращаешься к первому элементу списка. Вряд ли можно вывести все статусы, если обращаешься только к одному, так ведь?..

Comment: да, если поменять на 1 будет другой статус

Comment: В каком виде вы хотите получить необходимые данные?

Comment: И еще, у Вас JSON с ошибками. Либо это JSON и тогда не должно быть запятых перед закрывающими скобками, либо это словарь, и тогда там не должно быть значения `null`. А вообще попробуйте использовать библиотеку `jmespath`

Answer (score 0):

`pip install jmespath`

```py
import jmespath as jp
import json
data = json.loads(
    """{
  "trackingsDto": null,
  "detailedTrackingsWithMultiMailDto": null,
  "detailedTrackings": [
    {
      "userTrackingItemId": null,
      "trackingItem": {
        "destinationCountryName": "Россия",
        "destinationCountryNameGenitiveCase": "России",
        "title": "Мелкий пакет из Китая",
        "trackingHistoryItemList": [
          {
            "date": "2023-01-10T10:06:17.041+03:00",
            "humanStatus": "Получено адресатом"
          },
          {
            "date": "2022-12-01T11:54:19.000Z",
            "humanStatus": "Подготовлено к отправке"
          }
        ],
        "globalStatus": "ARCHIVED",
        "mailType": "Мелкий пакет"
      },
      "alienOrder": null
    }
  ]
}"""
)

print(jp.search(
    'detailedTrackings[*].trackingItem.trackingHistoryItemList[*].humanStatus[]',
    data
))
```

---

```
['Получено адресатом', 'Подготовлено к отправке']
```